# Why no safety measures for air passengers?

Tags: aircraft-design, parachute

Why have parachutes not been provided/safety measures taken in passenger carrying aircraft in case of a crash, so that at least they have some chance of survival?

It's like you are stuck in a bottle but until now, I am looking for an answer for how to save peoples' lives?

Even our cars have airbags in case of an accident but why nothing for air passengers?

Why is it not possible?

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Aviation.SE. Your question is not clear.  The title asks "why no safety measures" but there are many safety measures.  Then the question asks about parachutes and air bags.  Exactly what are you trying to ask?

Comment: By safety measures i mean for example in emergencies; in cruises we have life boats, in cars we have airbags etc but in case of aircraft why shoudn't we have such thing. In case of crash u r just setting and waiting for death why not atleast try to save urself through  parachute?

Comment: There are all kinds of safety measures. Off the top of my head we have: seatbelts, seats that are tested to maintain their integrity under large amounts of force, emergency evacuation slides and rafts, emergency lighting, oxygen masks, cabin crew with emergency training, fire detection and suppression equipment, pre-flight checks, redundant systems for critical components, flight testing, an expansive regulatory regime, maintenance and inspection standards, directives to address risks, initial and recurring crew training in addressing emergencies, and crash fire rescue stationed at airports.

Comment: In any case, part of your question can be answered at [Why are commercial flights not equipped with parachutes for the passengers?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2186/why-are-commercial-flights-not-equipped-with-parachutes-for-the-passengers)

Comment: see the plethora of similar questions and rants. And keep in mind that most active measures (like parachutes...) require a level of proficiency and training for the user to have any benefit from them, to the point where in many cases an untrained person (like a passenger...) would be likely to be harmed by the tool rather than it preventing harm to him.