Book for non-aviator to undersand flight
I'm not a flyer (and likely never will be), but I'm fascinated by flight.  If I'm not trying to actually become a pilot (so I'm not concerned with all the minutia of safety regulations, certification, airline practice, maintenance, etc.), but just want to understand the basic dynamics of flying a plane (so that if I'm in a plane falling out of the sky I at least understand why), what should / could I read?
EDIT: Most lists I have found online follow the format of "Best Aviation Books" or "Best Aviation Books for new Flyers".  Which doesn't really apply here. Thx

Your question might be closed, as this is opinion-based. I think Flying: Answers From Inside the Cockpit has been popular, it's from a pilot, written for passengers, so it's accurate without the painful theory. Another suggestion is to look at flight simulation games user guides, they are accurate. Instructor Rod Machado (not the surfer) has many interesting videos online.

How technical can it be?

@mins thanks will check, sophit I'd prefer non technical as I feel a general overview shouldn't be bogged down in dense theory, but I'm also not afraid of 'technical' by any means

Wing push air down = air push wing up. Don't forget this on your journey, as many people will make it seem more complicated than this. Good luck!

If the topic is general interest, just going for a wander here in the 'related questions', finding someone who writes answers that suit you and exploring their other answers can be an entry point. See also some of the question tags such as https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airline-operations or the classic https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/2223/60886

I'd recommend ANA -- Aerodynamics for Naval Aviators by HH Hunt Jr.  It is a bit technical, but without a lot of heavy derivations.  You can find inexpensive paperback copies online or download a PDF from the FAA https://www.faa.gov/sites/faa.gov/files/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/00-80T-80.pdf

The FAA publish the Pilot's Handbook of Aeronautical Knowledge which is available as PDFs here: https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/phak  It's pretty comprehensive.

Aerodynamics for Naval Aviators  Is a classic used for pilot training.  It covers some aerodynamics as well as aircraft performance (how airplanes fly).
It is a little technical -- but without getting bogged down in all the derivations.  In my opinion, it is not possible to really understand this stuff without at least a few equations.  ANA skirts that minimum.
It is a publication of the US Government (NAVAIR) and is printed and made available by the FAA.  You can get an inexpensive paperback copy at any pilot shop or online.

This sounds like the type of book I'm looking for. I also find military manuals often stick to "just what your really need to know".  I'll throw it on my ereader and give it a try.
